# Disable touch drag

Tags: laptop, touchpad, trackpad, drag-and-drop

I am using touchpad on my laptop, but sometimes when I move pointer around it starts dragging (touch drag). I prefer to drag while holding it down.

Can this touch drag be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Install Synaptiks from Software Center.

Synaptiks is an application for editing touch-pad settings. I think it has an option for solving your problem.

[image: synaptiks]

Beware of size of this package.

Comment: Synaptiks is not available in software center. 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you open a terminal window, and use this command:

```
synclient TapAndDragGesture=0
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Fn + F3 will Disable the touch pad again to same to enable it

System Setting ---> Mouse& TouchPad

In TouchPad Setting trun off that slove

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and I had a similar problem. I installed "Pointing Devices" from the software center and made some modifications. The problem appears to have stopped for me.

I hope you have the same luck.

Cheers!